# How to split by HTML tags using a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"Energia Elétrica kWh<span class=\"_ _3\"> </span>  10.942 <span class=\"_ _4\"> </span> 0,74999294 <span class=\"_ _5\"> </span>     8.206,39"
```

and I want to split it by its HTML tags, which are always `<span>`. I tried something like:

```
my_string.split(/<span(.*)span>/)
```

but it didn't work, it only matched  the first element correctly.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my regex? In this example, I expected the returned value to be:

```
["Energia Elétrica kWh", "10.942", "0,74999294" ,"8.206,39"]
```

I would like something like `strip_tags`, but instead of returning the string sanitized, get the array split by the tags removed.

Comment: HTML is not suitable for regex manipulation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 Although it will incur a fair bit of overhead, I would use the nokogiri gem and extract that data you want using it's various methods. http://www.nokogiri.org/

Comment: I already have Nokogiri... but don't know any method could help me here. Any guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use regex to do this, you pretty much had it already.

```
irb(main):010:0> string.split(/<span.+?span>/)
=> ["Energia Eltrica kWh", "  10.942 ", " 0,74999294 ", "     8.206,39"]
```

You just needed the `?` to tell it to match as little as possible.

Comment: Regex are so fragile for trying to handle HTML/XML, that they're highly discouraged for that use. Only the most trivial uses, or highly controlled, are a reasonable fit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1 covers the issues well.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks bro

Comment: @theTinMan I agree with you, but in my case the format is rigid... so Steven's answer will work like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a pattern to manipulate HTML. It's a [path destined to make you insane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/128421).

Instead use a HTML parser. The standard for Ruby is [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("Energia Elétrica kWh<span class=\"_ _3\"> </span>  10.942 <span class=\"_ _4\"> </span> 0,74999294 <span class=\"_ _5\"> </span>     8.206,39")
```

You could use `text` to extract all the text, but, if it's structured data you're after, that often makes it difficult to extract the fields because the text nodes can be concatenated resulting in run-on words, so be careful there:

```
doc.text # => "Energia Elétrica kWh   10.942   0,74999294       8.206,39"
```

Instead we typically extract the data from individual nodes:

```
doc.search('span')[1].next_sibling.text # => " 0,74999294 "
doc.search('span').last.next_sibling.text # => "     8.206,39"
```

Or, we iterate over the nodes, then use `map` to grab the node's text:

```
doc.search('span').map{ |span| span.next_sibling.text.strip }
# => ["10.942", "0,74999294", "8.206,39"]
```

I'd go about the problem like this:

```
data = [doc.at('span').previous_sibling.text.strip] # => ["Energia Elétrica kWh"]
data += doc.search('span').map{ |span| span.next_sibling.text.strip } 
# => ["Energia Elétrica kWh", "10.942", "0,74999294", "8.206,39"]
```

Or:

```
spans = doc.search('span')
data = [
  spans.first.previous_sibling.text,
  *spans.map{ |span| span.next_sibling.text }
].map(&:strip)
# => ["Energia Elétrica kWh", "10.942", "0,74999294", "8.206,39"]
```

While a regular expression can often work on an initial attempt, a change in the format of the HTML can break the pattern, forcing an additional change, then another change, and then another, until the pattern is too convoluted, whereas a properly written parser approach will typically be very resilient and immune to the problem.

Comment: I'm using nokogiri, but couldn't think how to get that array from the string. That method you suggest could help to get some values, but don't think of it as a good way to get the array... gonna edit the question to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's an excellent way to get at the data, but you weren't patient. It takes time to put together good answers that educate.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but what I was thinking is  something like Steven B answer... so much more simple! Thanks bro